# Copyright for unlicense debian machine readable format

Tags: debian, packaging, licenses

For distributing [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) I would like to add a minimal debian machine readable copyright file.

What should the `copyright` field have? It is licensed under [unlicense.org](http://unlicense.org)

```
Format:http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/
Files:*
Copyright:public domain
License:unlicense.org
```

Comment: Whoever it is copyrighted by. But youtube-dl is already in Debian, so I'm unclear what the point of this is. You can find the copyright file at `/usr/share/doc/youtube-dl/copyright` after installing (`apt-get install youtube-dl`).

Comment: Seconding @FaheemMitha, here's the current `copyright` file on jessie: http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/y/youtube-dl/youtube-dl_2014.08.05-1+deb8u1_copyright

Comment: Thank you. It is not in wheezy repositories : D

Comment: You can probably rebuild the current package on Wheezy: `dget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/y/youtube-dl/youtube-dl_2016.02.22-1.dsc`, then change into the extracted directory and `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` (but I imagine you knew that already).

Comment: I'd add the `-b` option to that `dpkg-buildpackage` command to build the binary .deb package only and  avoid unnecessary build of source packages.

Answer (score 1):

When packaging software for a distribution, follow their guidelines on how and where to place the license file. You will probably have to place the original license text somewhere, or link to some central copy. You should be able to rip off the way other packages do it.

This is covered in detail in the guidelines to create packages for e.g. Fedora, I'd be surprised if it wasn't also included in Debian. It is an one-time cost, better pay it upfront, your home knit package might go official, and fixing that later on is a hassle if it got released into the wild (and even inadvertently go against the license, getting you in legal trouble).

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. Please note that the question was: `What should the copyright field have? It is licensed under unlicense.org` and it is: `not applicable` : D

Comment: @ncomputers.org, filch it from another package with the same license, if the guidelines aren't clear enough. Not a Debian user myself, I couldn't say.

Answer (score -1):

For unlicensed software, a minimal debian machine readable copyright file should be:

```
Format:http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/
Files:*
Copyright:not applicable
License:public-domain
 explanation of the exemption
```